# Pandas series changes to int unexpectedly when i run a for loop on it

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series of test scores which i am trying to standardize.

```
input:
df['testscores'].head()
output:
0    509
1    499
2    511
3    495
4    520

mean = df['testscores'].mean()
std = df['testscores'].std()
    for i, v in enumerate(new_df['testscores']):
        new_df['testscores'][i] = (v - mean) / std
```

I expected the output to be series of floats, however, the output is a series of int. I need the ints to be floats, as the decimal places are important for me. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What is `new_df['testscores'].dtype` prior to `enumerate` operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time you try to assign values to it in your last line, `new_df['testscores']` is already an initialized series (apparently).  As such, it has a defined dtype, which is apparently an integer type.

To verify, inspect `print(new_df['testscores'].dtype)`.

One way, but unlikely the best, is to "change" the dtype of that series:

```
new_df['testscores'] = new_df['testscores'].astype(float)
```

You're not so much changing the dtype as reassigning to a copy of the series, but it would work.

A better way is, instead of reusing your 'testscores' series, creating a new series (with correct dtype) and assigning to that:

```
new_df["zscore"] = pd.Series(dtype=float)
```

then

```
mean = df['testscores'].mean()
std  = df['testscores'].std()
for i, v in enumerate(new_df['testscores']):
    new_df['zscore'][i] = (v - mean) / std
```

The last line could/should be changed to

```
new_df.loc[i,'zscore'] = (v - mean) / std
```

to avoid a [chained index (and a warning in my version)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy).

***But wait***

As pointed out in the comments by [John Galt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2137255/john-galt), the explicit loop is unnecessary, and everything can(should) be reduced to

```
mean = df['testscores'].mean()
std  = df['testscores'].std()
new_df['zscore'] = (new_df['testscores'] - mean) / std
```

Additionally, by using this method the dtype of the series will be inferred, so you can skip the

```
new_df["zscore"] = pd.Series(dtype=float)
```

line.

Comment: And, you can just do, `new_df['zscore'] = (new_df['testscores'] - mean) / std`, without needing to loop'?

Comment: Absolutely, I was going to edit in a fix to the chained indexing, but I missed the forest for the trees.

Comment: Thank you, this worked great! Why does `new_df['zscore'] = (new_df['testscores'] - mean) / std` correctly iterate through each item in the old series and outputs the correct z-value into the new series, rather then outputting only the first z-score to ALL the items in the new series? Is it because we are assigning values to a new, blank series?

Answer (score 0):

To get unit variance:

```
df['unitvariance'] = (df - df.mean())/df.std()
```